Why does my gams code throw errors and doesn't return what I want?
My GAMS code throws errors, but I can't figure out why. Can you please help?
SETS
    i beds /1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10/
    w weaving machines /W1,W2,W3,W4/
    h handle machines  /H1,H2,H3,H4/
    e embriodery machines  /E1,E2/
;

PARAMETERS
    demand(i) demand of bed i /1 545, 2 266, 3 179, 4 170, 5 137, 6 88, 7 83, 8 80, 9 67, 10 64/
    max_work_time maximum work time for each machine /5850/
    D(i,w) duration of bed i for operation o in machine w /1.W3 2.212,
                                                             1.W4 2.459,
                                                             2.W3 1.336,
                                                             2.W4 1.336,
                                                             3.W3 1.406,
                                                             3.W4 1.406,
                                                             4.W1 2.554,
                                                             4.W2 2.554,
                                                             5.W3 2.413,
                                                             5.W4 2.413,
                                                             6.W3 2.691,
                                                             6.W4 2.691,
                                                             7.W3 2.398,
                                                             7.W4 2.398,
                                                             8.W3 1.204,
                                                             8.W4 1.204,
                                                             9.W1 2.624,
                                                             9.W2 2.624,
                                                            10.W3 0.238,
                                                            10.W4 0.238/
    S(i,e) duration of bed i for operation o in machine e  / 1.E1 2.113,
                                                            1.E2 2.113,
                                                            5.E1 2.150,
                                                            5.E2 2.150,
                                                            6.E1 2.485,
                                                            6.E2  2.485,
                                                            7.E1 2.150,
                                                            7.E2 2.150/
    F(i,h)  duration of bed i for operation o in machine h /1.H3 0.154,
                                                           1.H4 0.154,
                                                            2.H1 0.162,
                                                            2.H2 0.162,
                                                            3.H1 0.154,
                                                            3.H2 0.154,
                                                            4.H3 0.154,
                                                            4.H4 0.154,
                                                            5.H3 0.154,
                                                            5.H4 0154,
                                                            6.H3 0.154,
                                                            6.H4 0.154,
                                                            7.H1 0.162,
                                                            7.H2 0.162,
                                                            8.H1 0.154,
                                                            8.H2 0.154,
                                                            9.H1 0.154,
                                                            9.H2 0.154,
                                                            10.H1 1.846,
                                                            10.H2 1.846/
     ;
Table
R(w,i) relation between machine j and bed i
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
W1  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
W2  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
W3  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
W4  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 ;

Table
P(h,i)
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
H1  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
H2  0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
H3  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
H4  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ;

Table
U(e,i)
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
E1  1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
E2  1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ;

;
VARIABLES
    X(i,w) binary variable indicating if bed i is produced in machine j for operation o(weaving)
    Y(i,h) binary variable indicating if bed i is produced in machine j for operation o
    Z(i,e) binary variable indicating if bed i is produced in machine j for operation o
    
    T(i,w)  starting time of operation o for bed i on machine w
    L(i,h)  starting time of operation o for bed i on machine h
    J(i,e)  starting time of operation o for bed i on machine e
    
    Comp(i) completion time of each i
    z       total completion time to be minimized
;

BINARY VARIABLES
    X(i,w)
    Y(i,h) 
    Z(i,e)
;

EQUATIONS
    objective        objective function to minimize total completion time
    a(i,w)
    b(i,h)
    v(i,e)
    priority_weaving(i,w,h) ensures that weaving is completed before handle
    priority_handle(i,h,e) ensures that handle is completed before embroidery
    e1(w)
    e2(h)
    e3(e)
    
    c5(i)
    c6(i,w)
    c7(i,h)
    c8(i,e)

    balance(i)      ensures that production balanced for every machine
    balance2(i)
    c2(i)            ensures that the production meets the demand
    c4(i)            ensures that the completion time is correctly calculated
    
    h1
    h2
    h3
    h4
    ;

objective.. z =e= sum(i, Comp(i) * demand(i));

c4(i).. sum(e,J(i,e)+ S(i,e)) =e= Comp(i);
a(i,w).. X(i,w) =l= R(w,i);
b(i,h).. Y(i,h) =l= P(h,i);
v(i,e).. Z(i,e) =l=U(e,i);
e1(w)..sum(i,X(i,w)*D(i,w)) =l= max_work_time;
e2(h)..sum(i,Y(i,h)*F(i,h)) =l= max_work_time;
e3(e)..sum(i,Z(i,e)*S(i,e)) =l= max_work_time;
priority_weaving(i,w,h).. T(i,w)+D(i,w)*X(i,w) =l= L(i,h);
priority_handle(i,h,e).. L(i,h)+ F(i,h)*Y(i,h) =l= J(i,e);
c2(i)..sum(h,Y(i,h)) =g= demand(i);
balance(i).. sum(w,X(i,w)) =e= sum(h,Y(i,h))/4;
balance2(i).. sum(h,Y(i,h))/8 =e= sum(e,Z(i,e));
h1..T("1","W3") =e= 0.000;
h2..T("1","W4") =e= 0.000;
h3..T("4","W1") =e= 0.000;
h4..T("4","W2") =e= 0.000;
c5(i).. Comp(i) =g= 0;
c6(i,w).. T(i,w) =g= 0;
c7(i,h).. L(i,h) =g= 0;
c8(i,e).. J(i,e) =g= 0;
MODEL Scheduling /all /;
SOLVE Scheduling USING RMINLP MINIMIZING z;


Which errors does it throw? What result do you want? What do you want to do?

Hello, ERROR 148 for objective constraint. 148, 246, 257 for SOLVE (I think bc of obj constraint). I want it to give me scheduling for operations and minimize the total completion time (objective).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The first error I get is
Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
   indices as declared

The reason is, that you use variable z sometimes as a scalar variable (just z -> single record) and sometimes as z(i,e). So, if that should be two different variables, you need to rename either the one or the other or you need to decide which version is the correct one and adjust the other accordingly.
